# Android NDK Firebase Crashlytics Symbolication ( C++ )

Tags: android, firebase, android-ndk, crashlytics

I'm getting NDK Crashes in Firebase from my Android app written in java, but there is no symbolication for them, only:

```
SEGV 0x0000000000000000
libnative-lib.so
(Missing UUID bbcaa3aa5d4aea6d2f4865d907eced52ccb8835a)
libart.so
(Missing UUID adb75d6f792faa24b1bc8cf512fb112c)
```

I've followed all indications from the Firebase documentation but still nothing.

Here's my app level gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.8.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And app level gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplicationid"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 10
        versionName '1.2'
        multiDexEnabled true

        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-ljnigraphics -Wl,--build-id=none"
            }
        }

        ndk {
            stl "stlport_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            /* Add the firebaseCrashlytics extension (by default,
            * it's disabled to improve build speeds) and set
            * nativeSymbolUploadEnabled to true. */

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
            }

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        debug {
            /* Add the firebaseCrashlytics extension (by default,
            * it's disabled to improve build speeds) and set
            * nativeSymbolUploadEnabled to true. */

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
            }

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
            version "3.10.2"
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        GoogleFlavor {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".google"
        }
        SamsungFlavor {
            dimension "version"
            applicationIdSuffix = ".samsung"

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
            }
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'
    implementation project(path: ':IAP6Helper')

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:4.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:12.1.0'

    // Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.0.0')

    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.9'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.1.0')
    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics NDK dependency.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk:18.2.9'

    // Pull and compile the latest release of the Amazon Appstore SDK
    implementation 'com.amazon.device:amazon-appstore-sdk:3.0.2'
}
```

And pro guard:

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable        # Keep file names and line numbers.
-keep public class * extends
```

What could it be ? I'm stuck with this for days and can't figure it out.

Comment: I'd doubt that it even would build with `jcenter()` and the ProGuard rules are for Java.

Comment: It builds with jcenter() . And yes I'm building a Java Android App that uses an NDK C++ native library. Also, I'm an iOS developer trying to learn Android programming, sorry for the obvious mistakes :)